# What is a gabor filter?

Tags: image-processing, imagefilter

I would like to know more about Gabor 1D and 2D kernels.

I am a newbie to the field of image processing.

When I search for this question in google, It throws up a lot of results, but all those links including those of wikipedia`s is not suited for beginners like me.

Kindly suggest some links to articles especially for BEGINNERS.

or even better,

It would be great if someone can give a detailed explaination to Gabor Filters for BEGINNERS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would like to know also. Any luck ? Did you find some good explanation? please share it

Comment: You can try asking at Signal Processing forum - http://dsp.stackexchange.com/. Or better yes help us create the Image Processing forum at: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66531/computer-vision Just up vote question with less than 10 votes. Thank You.